# Airflow: Convert step function cycle task to airflow

Tags: amazon-web-services, airflow, aws-step-functions, directed-acyclic-graphs, mwaa

I have 4 step functions to perform certain tasks. All four use the same API key to call external API. Since the key has a limited call rate and to reduce the API call failing I am running step functions at different times using event bridge(cron express).

As we know this is not a good approach, because here next step function is not triggering immediately after the completion of the previous step function. It will be triggering only when its scheduled time comes. I found one solution for this - Take all the tasks of each step function and put them into one step function. Tasks are executed serially.

I decided to try with airflow once and started writing the DAG. Now I am facing the difficulty to convert the step function flow to airflow. Because in the step function, I am using the choice state to decide the termination of a step function, and also if the termination condition is not met then it will call the previous state. This will continue until the stop condition is met. (Attached sample image below)

[image: state-machine]

I know we cannot have this kind of cycle dependency in airflow. I want to know that is there any way that we can achieve this kind of flow in airflow. Thank you!.